# Managing passkeys with a less-than-trustworthy Android device

Tags: google-account, authentication, passkey

I have an old Android device that I sometimes use. Presumably it is full of critical security holes, but the value I get from using it is much less than the cost of a newer device, especially since said newer device will be in exactly the same situation a few years after I buy it.

I noticed today that this old device has an entry for an "Automatically created passkey" at https://g.co/passkeys

I think this means that Google is trusting this device to hold a cryptographic secret that would let *more* devices log into my Google account.

How do I communicate to Google that this device is untrustworthy, and revoke its stored passkey? (And also probably disable sign-in-via-notification on the device?) Can I clear the keys from the device somehow or will it just make more?

Is the only way to prevent Google from trusting the device to authenticate new sessions to sign the device out of my account completely?

Comment: "*Is the only way to prevent Google from trusting the device to authenticate new sessions to sign the device out of my account completely?*" based on the information on the linked Google page there, I'm afraid it is, similar to the push notification.